# Exporting Global Styles with Font Assets from a TypeScript->CommonJS module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, gatsby, yarnpkg

I have a TypeScript React project organized as follows:

```
tsconfig.json
package.json
yarn.lock
lerna.json
node_modules/
packages/
  ui-library/
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    typings.d.ts
    src/
      fonts/
        myfont.ttf
      components/
        GlobalStyle.tsx
    lib/ <-- `tsc` builds to here
  web-app/
   package.json
   src/
    components/
```

The `web-app` imports the `ui-library` as a commonjs module in its package.json.  This is managed through Yarn Workspaces, hence node_modules being at the root instead of each folder.  At one point, the web-app imports `GlobalStyle` from the ui-lib, which is where the issue occurs.

```
Error: Cannot find module '../fonts/myfont.ttf'
Require stack:
 - /Users/me/sources/myproject/packages/ui-library/lib/styles/GlobalStyle.js...
```

Here is the original import statement from `ui-library/src/GlobalStyle.tsx` that causes the issue:

```
import myFont from "../fonts/myfont.ttf";

const GlobalStyle = () => (
  <style global jsx>{`
    @font-face {
      font-family: "My font family";
      src: url(${myFont}) format("truetype");
    }
  ...</style>);
```

The issue is the `require` statement in the emitted GlobalStyle.js code, built when I run `tsc` in the ui-lib folder:

`const MYFONT_ttf_1 = __importDefault(require("./myfont.ttf"));`

I googled this issue online, and I found you had to add typings for compiling `.ttf` and other abnormal imports.  So I created a `typings.d.ts` file with this declaration:

```
declare module "*.ttf" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

And I included it on `ui-library/tsconfig.json` as follows:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["lib"],
  "include": ["src"],
  "files": ["./typings.d.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "noEmit": false
  }
}
```

The tsconfig above extends the root tsconfig:

```
{
  "files": ["./typings.d.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2019",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2019"],
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "declaration": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

We are using TypeScript 3.8.  Let me know if there is any additional info to provide.  My hunch is that I am either using the wrong module/target, or fundamentally misunderstanding some aspect of this.

**More Details**
I should note the reason we are using CommonJS modules is because ts-node can only work with that.  We pull in ts-node when we are doing our gatsby build, [following the gist here](http://%20https://gist.github.com/JohnAlbin/2fc05966624dffb20f4b06b4305280f9) in `gatsby-config.js`:

```
require("ts-node").register();

// Use a TypeScript version of gatsby-config.js.
module.exports = require("./gatsby-config.ts");
```

Maybe it's an impossible problem to solve, to get fonts imported through ts-node which is a server side environment? Confused on what the right approach is to export a module with fonts.  Willing to get rid of ts-node, and leave the Gatsby config files as js.. but mostly just want to be able to import my fonts.

Comment: TTF/OTF/... imports in client-side apps are handled by the bundler, which converts them into e.g. data URLs. That's the missing part in your server-side equation here.

Comment: @AKX If I understand correctly, the .js output has require(myfontasset), but this is converted to data urls on a later step?  Is the issue that I am not transpiling require() into data, or that require is there in the first place?

Comment: Recommend these articles for anyone figuring it out, explained a lot to me https://www.zachleat.com/web/comprehensive-webfonts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by just copying the fonts as part of build steps.  Basically, fonts have their own pipeline.  There may be better ways, but this works well enough.

Answer (score 2):

I have `theme` package where I have global `theme.css` styles with local fonts inside. Then I just added `theme/theme.css` to my app entry point. That's it. I use `windicss` if it helps

[image]

[image]

[image]